# Main-Class in a Manifest file in a WAR

Tags: java, manifest.mf, war-filedeployment

I am trying to create a restful webservice. 
Followed this tutorial - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html

This project has 2 files -

1. a resource class HelloWorld.java.
2. a configuration class MyApplication.java.

I had IntelliJ generate a WAR file as an artifact. 
I added a MANIFEST.MF file to the WAR file. Contest of this file -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

Question - Should the Main-Class be HelloWorld or MyApplication?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. A WAR file is essentially a collection of Servlets, invoked by the container. No main class required.